# Tabcontent shall always align with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have three 3 Relative layout in a LinearLayout.
First Relative layout contains Tabhost.
All Tabhost content should be aligned above the 2nd RelativeLayout at all times.
The problem is the content is always viewed as behind the 3rd and 2nd Relative Layout.
How can it make as always above the 2nd RelativeLayout?

[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark">

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:gravity="top"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="62dp"/>

    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_for_sip_active"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#19c031"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Online"
            android:id="@+id/online_offline"
            android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
            android:textColor="#afafaf"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="On going call....."
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:id="@+id/callcounter"
            android:textColor="#afafaf"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/unmute"
            android:onClick="Unmute"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_mute"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mute"
            android:onClick="Mute"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_mute_active"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="26dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/demute"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_mute_inactive"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
        style="@style/Theme.Callbox"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_addtarget"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_call"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_btm_actionbar"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:onClick="Call" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_addtarget_end"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_btm_actionbar"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_end_call"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:onClick="endCall" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_dialpad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_dialer"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_btm_actionbar"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:onClick="showDialpad"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/dummy"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_btm_actionbar"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:onClick="showCallResult"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_process_save"
            android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar_addtarget_end"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/fl_slide_pop">
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: your linear layout is still open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things are bad in your design.
You have too many Layouts, I tried to remove as much as possible some of them.

Also you have 3 ImageButtons for mute/unmute/demute where only one can be set an programmatically changed.

Inflating a view is kind of heavy on android if you don't optimized it.

There is a [tool](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) into the SDK that help you to see your layout hierarchy in order to see how to optimized it
You can try to do something simpler like this example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!-- here is the bottom layout which contains your 3 buttons -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/third_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- Here is the equivalent of the 2nd relative layout, but you just have to show a image 
    button or a Text view, you don't have to use another relative layout -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mute"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/third_layout"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/third_layout"
        />

    <!-- finally the 1st layout which is above the second to the top of its parent -->

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/mute"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

        <!-- TAB Widget -->

    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I encourage you to use less layout in order to have a smoother application.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, a very useful tip will use it from now on. Btw, just to add a question how do you place the tabwidget on the top? instead in the bottom?